# How to identify and compare thread-ids

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have Class named `Home` in my shared library. I have a multi-threaded  application in which I need to create an instance to this Class `Home`. Now for every thread instantiating this class I need to create a separate trace file based on the thread-id in the class constructor. My problem is, I am not able to use the return value from `pthread_self()` either as `int` or `long int`(which is an opaque type called `pthread_t`) as a reference during the creation of the trace file. I Need to differentiate threads based on their thread-ids and use them as references during the creation of corresponding trace files. Please tell me a way to sort out this. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Please tell me if you need any more details.

Comment: Maybe this helps.The pthread_equal() function is needed to compare thread ids because the pthread_t data type must be treated as opaque data.

Comment: `int pthread_equal(pthread_t t1, pthread_t t2);` compares the thread IDs t1 and t2. But I want something like `if(t1 == somevalue){//create a file;}`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use e.g. [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) with the `pthread_t` as key, and use the distance from the `begin` iterator to the newly inserted `pthread_t` as key?

Something like

```
std::unordered_set<pthread_t> ids;

...

int get_id(const pthread_t& tid)
{
    const auto it = ids.find(tid);
    if (it == ids.end())
    {
        // Thread id not found, insert it
        const auto pair = ids.insert(tid);
        if (!pair.second)
            return -1;  // Failed to insert
        it = pair.first;
    }

    // Return the distance between the beginning and the position of the thread-id
    return std::distance(ids.begin(), it);
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tested (or even tried to compile) this.

Also note that I use the C++11 `std::unordered_set` class, as well as the type inference `auto` keyword that was also introduced in C++11.